# Not able to sort array of objects

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have following array:

```
[
    {
        "BestCoupon": 1,
        "Saving": "100",
        "Successful": 1,
        "couponCode": "CRIC100",
        "description": "Get Rs. 100 Discount on purchase of Rs. 599 & above. Products include Eyeglasses & Sunglasses and more. Choose",
        "domain": "www.lenskart.com",
        "url": "http://www.lenskart.com/checkout/cart/"
    },
    {
        "BestCoupon": 0,
        "Saving": "NOT APPLICABLE :Coupon code \"CRIC200\" is not valid.",
        "Successful": 0,
        "couponCode": "CRIC200",
        "description": "Get Rs. 200 Discount on purchase of Rs. 999 & above. Products include Eyeglasses & Sunglasses and more. Choose",
        "domain": "www.lenskart.com",
        "url": "http://www.lenskart.com/checkout/cart/"
    },
    {
        "BestCoupon": 0,
        "Saving": "NOT APPLICABLE : Coupon code \"CRIC300\" is not valid.",
        "Successful": 0,
        "couponCode": "CRIC300",
        "description": "Get Rs. 300 Discount on purchase of Rs. 1199 & above. Products include Eyeglasses, Sunglasses & Contact Lenses",
        "domain": "www.lenskart.com",
        "url": "http://www.lenskart.com/checkout/cart/"
    },
    {
        "BestCoupon": 0,
        "Saving": "NOT APPLICABLE: Coupon code \"JJPREMIUM\" is not valid.",
        "Successful": 0,
        "couponCode": "JJPREMIUM",
        "description": "Get Rs 600 Discount on John Jacobs Eyeglasses. Products include Eyeglasses. Choose from brand like John",
        "domain": "www.lenskart.com",
        "url": "http://www.lenskart.com/checkout/cart/"
    },
    {
        "BestCoupon": 0,
        "Saving": "NOT APPLICABLE: Coupon code \"LENS20130303\" is not valid.",
        "Successful": 0,
        "couponCode": "LENS20130303",
        "description": "Get Rs. 500 Discount on purchase of Rs. 1000. Products include Eyeglasses, Sunglasses & Contact Lenses and",
        "domain": "www.lenskart.com",
        "url": "http://www.lenskart.com/checkout/cart/"
    },
    {
        "BestCoupon": 0,
        "Saving": "179.8",
        "Successful": 1,
        "couponCode": "LKEND20",
        "description": "Get 20% Discount on Eyeglasses. Minimum Purchase Rs. 499. Products include Eyeglasses. Choose from brandslike",
        "domain": "www.lenskart.com",
        "url": "http://www.lenskart.com/checkout/cart/"
    },
    {
        "BestCoupon": 0,
        "Saving": "224.75",
        "Successful": 1,
        "couponCode": "LKEND25",
        "description": "Flat 25% off on purchase of Rs 799 & above",
        "domain": "www.lenskart.com",
        "url": "http://www.lenskart.com/checkout/cart/"
    },
    {
        "BestCoupon": 0,
        "Saving": "NOT APPLICABLE : Coupon code \"LKEND30\" is not valid.",
        "Successful": 0,
        "couponCode": "LKEND30",
        "description": "Get 30% Discount on purchase of Rs 1299 & above. Products include Eyeglasses, Sunglasses & Contact Lenses and",
        "domain": "www.lenskart.com",
        "url": "http://www.lenskart.com/checkout/cart/"
    },
    {
        "BestCoupon": 0,
        "Saving": "NOT APPLICABLE : Coupon code \"LKEND35\" is not valid.",
        "Successful": 0,
        "couponCode": "LKEND35",
        "description": "Get 35% Discount on purchase of Rs 1499 & above. Products include Eyeglasses, Sunglasses & Contact Lenses and",
        "domain": "www.lenskart.com",
        "url": "http://www.lenskart.com/checkout/cart/"
    },
    {
        "BestCoupon": 0,
        "Saving": "100",
        "Successful": 1,
        "couponCode": "OMGABV600",
        "description": "Get Rs. 100 Discounton order of Rs. 600 & Above. Products include Eyeglasses, Sunglasses & Contact Lenses and",
        "domain": "www.lenskart.com",
        "url": "http://www.lenskart.com/checkout/cart/"
    },
    {
        "BestCoupon": 0,
        "Saving": "NOT APPLICABLE : Coupon code \"POWERSUN20\" isnot valid.",
        "Successful": 0,
        "couponCode": "POWERSUN20",
        "description": "Get 20% OFFon Power Sunglasses. Select from a vast collection.",
        "domain": "www.lenskart.com",
        "url": "http://www.lenskart.com/checkout/cart/"
    },
    {
        "BestCoupon": 0,
        "Saving": "179.8",
        "Successful": 1,
        "couponCode": "WEEKEND20",
        "description": "Flat 20% OFF on purchase of Rs 499 & above - NA on Premium Brands & Contact Lenses",
        "domain": "www.lenskart.com",
        "url": "http://www.lenskart.com/checkout/cart/"
    }
]
```

I want to sort it in the descending order of "Savings". Am using the following code

```
couponObj.sort(function (a, b) {
      if (a[0].Saving == b[0].Saving)
         return 0;
      if (a[0].Saving > b[0].Saving)
         return -1;
      if (a[0].Saving < b[0].Saving)
         return 1;
});
```

Its giving me the following result :

```
[
    {
        "BestCoupon": 0,
        "Saving": "NOT APPLICABLE : Coupon code \"POWERSUN20\" is not valid.",
        "Successful": 0,
        "couponCode": "POWERSUN20",
        "description": "Get 20% OFF on Power Sunglasses. Select from a vast collection.",
        "domain": "www.lenskart.com",
        "url": "http://www.lenskart.com/checkout/cart/"
    },
    {
        "BestCoupon": 0,
        "Saving": "NOT APPLICABLE : Coupon code \"LKEND35\" is not valid.",
        "Successful": 0,
        "couponCode": "LKEND35",
        "description": "Get 35% Discount on purchase of Rs 1499 & above. Products include Eyeglasses, Sunglasses & Contact Lenses and",
        "domain": "www.lenskart.com",
        "url": "http://www.lenskart.com/checkout/cart/"
    },
    {
        "BestCoupon": 0,
        "Saving": "NOT APPLICABLE : Coupon code \"LKEND30\" is not valid.",
        "Successful": 0,
        "couponCode": "LKEND30",
        "description": "Get 30% Discount on purchase of Rs 1299 & above. Products include Eyeglasses, Sunglasses & Contact Lenses and",
        "domain": "www.lenskart.com",
        "url": "http://www.lenskart.com/checkout/cart/"
    },
    {
        "BestCoupon": 0,
        "Saving": "NOT APPLICABLE : Coupon code \"LENS20130303\" is not valid.",
        "Successful": 0,
        "couponCode": "LENS20130303",
        "description": "Get Rs. 500 Discount on purchase of Rs. 1000. Products include Eyeglasses, Sunglasses & Contact Lenses and",
        "domain": "www.lenskart.com",
        "url": "http://www.lenskart.com/checkout/cart/"
    },
    {
        "BestCoupon": 0,
        "Saving": "NOT APPLICABLE : Coupon code \"JJPREMIUM\" is not valid.",
        "Successful": 0,
        "couponCode": "JJPREMIUM",
        "description": "Get Rs 600 Discount on John Jacobs Eyeglasses. Products include Eyeglasses. Choose from brand like John",
        "domain": "www.lenskart.com",
        "url": "http://www.lenskart.com/checkout/cart/"
    },
    {
        "BestCoupon": 0,
        "Saving": "NOT APPLICABLE : Coupon code \"CRIC300\" is not valid.",
        "Successful": 0,
        "couponCode": "CRIC300",
        "description": "Get Rs. 300 Discount on purchase of Rs. 1199 & above. Products include Eyeglasses, Sunglasses & Contact Lenses",
        "domain": "www.lenskart.com",
        "url": "http://www.lenskart.com/checkout/cart/"
    },
    {
        "BestCoupon": 0,
        "Saving": "NOT APPLICABLE : Coupon code \"CRIC200\" is not valid.",
        "Successful": 0,
        "couponCode": "CRIC200",
        "description": "Get Rs. 200 Discount on purchase of Rs. 999 &above. Products include Eyeglasses & Sunglasses and more. Choose",
        "domain": "www.lenskart.com",
        "url": "http://www.lenskart.com/checkout/cart/"
    },
    {
        "BestCoupon": 0,
        "Saving": "224.75",
        "Successful": 1,
        "couponCode": "LKEND25",
        "description": "Flat 25% off on purchase of Rs 799 & above",
        "domain": "www.lenskart.com",
        "url": "http://www.lenskart.com/checkout/cart/"
    },
    {
        "BestCoupon": 0,
        "Saving": "179.8",
        "Successful": 1,
        "couponCode": "LKEND20",
        "description": "Get 20% Discount on Eyeglasses. Minimum Purchase Rs. 499. Products include Eyeglasses. Choose from brands like",
        "domain": "www.lenskart.com",
        "url": "http://www.lenskart.com/checkout/cart/"
    },
    {
        "BestCoupon": 0,
        "Saving": "179.8",
        "Successful": 1,
        "couponCode": "WEEKEND20",
        "description": "Flat 20%OFF on purchase of Rs 499 & above - NA on Premium Brands & Contact Lenses",
        "domain": "www.lenskart.com",
        "url": "http://www.lenskart.com/checkout/cart/"
    },
    {
        "BestCoupon": 0,
        "Saving": "100",
        "Successful": 1,
        "couponCode": "CRIC100",
        "description": "Get Rs. 100 Discount on purchase of Rs. 599 & above. Products include Eyeglasses & Sunglasses and more. Choose",
        "domain": "www.lenskart.com",
        "url": "http://www.lenskart.com/checkout/cart/"
    },
    {
        "BestCoupon": 0,
        "Saving": "100",
        "Successful": 1,
        "couponCode": "OMGABV600",
        "description": "Get Rs. 100 Discount on order of Rs. 600 & Above. Products include Eyeglasses, Sunglasses & Contact Lenses and",
        "domain": "www.lenskart.com",
        "url": "http://www.lenskart.com/checkout/cart/"
    }
]
```

Basically it's sorting on top the array item where saving is a string. I want them at bottom.

Comment: Thats an array of objects, not a Json string

Comment: Why using `a[0].Saving` and not `a.Saving`?

Comment: I've edited your question to remove references to JSON since it doesn't seem to have any relation with it. Feel free to correct if I'm wrong.

Comment: A small suggestion: have an additional key called SavingText and move that 'Not applicable' text to there and set Saving to 0.

Comment: If you're confused about what they were talking about, JSON is a way of putting data in a string for transfer, while an object is how the actual data structure is used within JavaScript

Comment: Am sorry for the JSON reference... meant array instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to access a property `0` of your object which doesn't appear to exist; and at the same time as correcting that, make it easier to see what's going on.

```
couponObj.sort(function (a, b) {
    a = +a.Saving, b = +b.Saving; // cast Number
    // special cases
    if (a !== a || b !== b)           // If there is a NaN
        return (a !== a) - (b !== b); // move it to the end
    // classic descending sort
    return b - a;
});
```

Comment: +1 Why not the classical `return b - a`? Is there something different in JS?

Comment: I asked because one can never know with weak-typed languages like JS... perhaps there was something hidden (like your use of ===, but that at least I know)

Comment: considering he has various NaN values (the "text" values), perhaps it would be better to handle them as a special case :-)

Comment: @xanatos we know it's fine in this example because I already did a cast. You may have to consider if it will be okay if there was no cast and you expect different types

Comment: The NaN won't get moved, true. Let me fix this.

Comment: I dont like this function because it is hard to read and understand the code. It needs to many comments to explain what it actually does.

Comment: @Prcela the comments here are only for complete clarity; if I was not writing it as an example I would only have one comment e.g. `// NaN asc`, if even that

Answer (score 1):

As other have suggested, but with a caveat: you have various `Saving` that are text instead of descriptions...

```
couponObj.sort(function (a, b) {
    a = parseFloat(a.Saving); // cast to number
    b = parseFloat(b.Saving); // cast to number

    if (isNaN(a)) return isNaN(b) ? 0 : 1;
    if (isNaN(b)) return -1;

    return b - a; // descending order
});
```

When you try casting a non-number to a number with `+`, the returned number is `NaN` (a special value that doesn't sort very well). For this reason the various `if (isNaN())`

Note that in initial versions I had used `+a.Saving` to cast the string to a number, but I've changed it to `parseFloat`. There is a subtle difference with `null`: `+null === 0`, while `parseFloat(null) === NaN` (that then I can handle).

Comment: And let's hope `a` and `b` are not `null` ;)

Comment: @Oleg +null is 0... mmmmh

Comment: `+null.Saving` -> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'Saving' of null" because the property will be read before attempting to "cast" to number.

Comment: @Oleg Ah... No I was thinking of `a.Saving` that could be `null` or `undefined`

Comment: Looks nice and neat. The example _JSON_ did not have any `null` entries, so I don't think we need to worry unless it get's said by OP

Comment: @PaulS. After some experimentings, it seems parseFloat(null) === parseFloat(undefined) === 0, while +null === 0, +undefined === NaN

Comment: @xanatos this is because `NaN` is not a _float_, it's `NaN`, and hence is mapped to _float_ `0`. The result of `+x` should match up with `new Number(x).valueOf()`

Answer (score 0):

When the comparator function is supplied to `Array.prototype.sort`, it is given arguments `a` and `b` which are elements of the original array, not the array itself.

So, in this particular case, you need to drop `[0]`. For example, instead of:

```
if (a[0].Saving == b[0].Saving) { ...
```

try:

```
if (a.Saving === b.Saving) { ...
           // ^-- also, it's best to use strict comparison
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the parseFloat method for the string conversion to floats:

```
couponObj.sort(function (a, b) {
  if(a && b) {
    var af = parseFloat(a.Saving);
    var bf = parseFloat(b.Saving);
    if(isNan(af)) return 1;
    if(isNan(bf)) return -1;
    return bf-af;
  }
  return 0; // ignore null entries
}
```